# passing strings to while loop

Tags: shell

I am trying to pass two strings to a while loop but i forgot the syntax please help me out.
This is what i am trying-

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do  
    echo "successful"
done < "var1" "var2" 
exit
```

I know i am doing something wrong here, i used to pass strings to while loop but i forgot the syntax. Please help me out here.

I am aware of -

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
   echo "successful"
done < "file_containing_var1_and_var2"
```

but i want to pass strings and not file to while loop, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<` redirection operator only works with files. for your requirement use a `for loop`

```
#!/bin/bash


for x in "var1" "var2"
do
   echo $x
done
```

Answer (score 4):

To pass string to your `while` loop, you need to use [herestring <<<](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection) notation.

```
$ while read line; do 
    echo "$line"
done <<< "This is my test line"
This is my test line
```

Comment: Hi JS, This is exactly what i wanted. can you please point out how do i pass more than one string here.

Comment: @user2118349 You are better off using a `for loop` as suggested by DevZer0, but if you must then you can do something like: `$ while IFS=: read string1 string2; do printf "%s\n%s\n" "$string1" "$string2"; done <<< "this is my string":"this is another string"`

Answer (score 2):

```
printf "%s\n" "var1" "var2" |
while read line
do  
    echo "successful: $line"
done
```

The `printf` command echoes each argument on a line on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe into a while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "var1" "var2" | while read line
do
    echo "successful: $line"
    set "$line"
    echo "v1: $1 v2: $2"
done
```

*Output*:

```
successful: var1 var2
v1: var1 v2: var2
```

Comment: Thanks perreal, jonathan and DevZero, Your answers added something new to my vault. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In case $line happens to begin with a hyphen, `set -- $line` (unquoted)